# "deprecations must be strings" error when publishing package to NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to publish a package using `npm publish` and this is what I got:

> npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 400
>
> npm ERR! code E400
>
> npm ERR! deprecations must be strings : async-csv
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-13T12_05_57_949Z-debug.log

I could not find a description of this error elsewhere. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

Found it. The error occurred because I was trying to publish the package without increasing the package version number in `package.json`.

Open the package.json, increase the version number and publish again.

Comment: weird, npm is usually pretty verbose about trying to publish over an existing version

Answer (score 1):

The error will occur if you are trying to publish the **same** version twice, or a version that is **lower** than the existing version. For example, if your last version was 1.0.1, and you are trying to publish as 1.0.0, it will make this error.